# Bootstrap Typeahead Dropdown BR Tags

Tags: jquery, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using the Bootstrap Typeahead - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead functionality to predict text in an input box.

I was wondering in the dropdown (that shows the predictive results) I could display each of the dropdown items on two lines. Suppose I am trying to predictive search between Organizations, but I also wanted to display the President of the Organization. How would I go about doing this.

I attempted to solve this problem in the following code. It displays the dropdown items on two lines showing both Organization and President. However when I select one of the dropdowns the "BR tag" shows up in my input text field. How would I fix this? Thanks

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root' ,'', 'test');
$query = $db->query("SELECT name,leader FROM organizations");
$orgs = array();
while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $orgs[] = $row['name'].'<br />'.$row['leader'];
}

$js_orgs = json_encode($orgs);

if($_POST){
    print_r($_POST);
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="demo.php">
    <input name="org" type="text" class="span3" id="search" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
var subjects = <?php echo $js_orgs; ?>; 
$('#search').typeahead({source: subjects, items:6})
</script>
```

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle showing my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/3dcbW/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this http://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/11/07/getting-more-from-twitter-bootstraps-typeahead-library/

you need to use the updater